# Is there a way to execute XSS in an HTML img tag with SVG?

Tags: xss, image, svg

Is there a working technique to execute XSS in modern browsers using a SVG file displayed on a web page with an `<img src="">` tag?

I know a way to execute without `<script>` tag, but I don't know how to load a file using SVG or anything else, because XML breaks when I try using different tags to get my XSS working.

Is this actually possible?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, it's not. Although SVG files can contain JS (see [this](https://shkspr.mobi/blog/2018/02/this-svg-always-shows-todays-date/)), these will only get executed if:

1. the user directly visits the `.svg` file in their browser
2. the image is embedded within `<embed>` tags.

Modern browsers will never execute scripts in SVGs if it's within `<img>` tags.

And even in the two cases above, the server can provide CSP headers that stop the execution of such scripts.

Comment: A third edge case would be a bug in the SVG implementation. I think this has happened.

Comment: `Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'none'`  Thanks for the CSP hint, I was afraid I'd have to pull up a second domain with its own cookie scope! This seems to do the trick and blocks both `<script>` tags and `onmouseover=...` attributes, so I assume it blocks all other types of scripting that the svg might contain as well. It seems to already be the default to contain any styles to the image itself (`<style>*{color:red}</style>` isn't being applied to the page where the `<img src=x.svg>` is on). Perhaps adding a `report-to` is also a good idea

Comment: This project aims to remove XSS from SVG images, in case that helps anyone: https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify

Answer (score 0):

SVG images can contain CSS, CSS are a possible injection point for XSS

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607894/cross-site-scripting-in-css-stylesheets
And https://code.google.com/archive/p/browsersec/wikis/Part1.wiki#Cascading_stylesheets

Which both point out

> As a little-known feature, some CSS implementations permit JavaScript
>   code to be embedded in stylesheets. There are at least three ways to
>   achieve this goal: by using the expression(...) directive, which gives
>   the ability to evaluate arbitrary JavaScript statements and use their
>   value as a CSS parameter; by using the url('javascript:...') directive
>   on properties that support it; or by invoking browser-specific
>   features such as the -moz-binding mechanism of Firefox.

So, yes, you can use user controlled SVG's to execute script in the domain of the host page.

Using Content-Security-Policy you can restrict where you expect to find styles or script. Another thing you could try is serve these SVG's in a sandboxed cross-domain iframe.

Comment: Sorry, that's not correct. An SVG in an `<img>` tag will not execute active script code. Also, JS in CSS expressions doesn't work in any modern browser.

Comment: @Arminius Well, i've been testing SVG and CSS+XSS for 6 months now, i found that SVG XSS is still working with data URI's(found a way to make a double embedded execution today, and then it works in any page), not sure if it's a real security bug. And CSS+XSS can work but only on <style> tag and in the same page of the <div>. I found that some tags are being blocked, like document. and window., but alert and prompt yet works using the same technique i found some months ago.
So it isn't so "impossible"! But it's really hard to test many codes to get it working.

Comment: @Mega Script code in SVGs is possible. But script code in SVGs embedded via `<img>` is strictly not possible. (Unless you found a bypass that constitutes a severe security issue.) Also, injecting script code via CSS is not possible. That is, if I embed an image or a stylesheet of your choice on my site, you will not be able to execute any Javascript through that.